# hands on axis2c api for cpp

Tags: web-services, apache, http, axis2c

I am new to webservices, I am trying to develop a http-client in c/cpp using apache axis2c.

I couldn't find any good sample code for axis2c api anywhere. documentation is also not that clear or straight forward to start developing client using axis2c.

any idea where can I get running sample code that can help me to start with.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://code.google.com/p/staff/wiki/StaffDetails#What_is_it?) (ws-staff) could be helpful to you.

I am also trying to create web service using C++. This seems to be a good start.

Comment: Please try not to give link-only answers. If the link goes down, then the answers becomes useless.